# How to single-escape a Pipe in a string: Unexpected str.replace behaviour

Tags: python, string, replace, escaping

Python's `str.replace` seems to be doing "clever" character escaping and the docs don't show any way to 'override' this behaviour.

Expected:

```py
x = "val|with|pipe"

x.replace("|","\|")
>>> "val\|with\|pipe"
```

Actual output:

```
x.replace("|","\|")
>>> "val\\|with\\|pipe"
```

Bonus Round:

```
x.replace('|','\\|')
>>> "val\\|with\\|pipe"
```

Comment: Your debug output is adding the second backslash, not the replace function.

Comment: `"\\"` is just a backslash, the first backslash is just the scaping

Comment: Ugh, that makes sense; unfortunately that means that my "root" problem is deeper than I'd hoped :(